# What is the joke that is shown in this picture?

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

There is supposedly a joke shown in this picture relating to periodic trends.
Does anyone know what it is? And could they also explain where the elements on the eye exam came from?
[image: The joke]

Comment: To me it's just a joke about how instead of random letters they're using random element symbols, probably inspired in part by the fact that several elements are represented by a single letter. I fail to see anything related to periodic trends.

Comment: Not entirely random. The elements are arranged in the same order they are found in a periodic table, reading as you would normally. It merely represents scientists using the periodic table as an eye chart.

Comment: I find it bizarre that Mg was dropped.  I suspect the artist found this version of the periodic table aesthetically pleasing?

Answer (score 6):

As commented by @long, **the elements shown are not completely randomised**. The elements in all the rows, except in the 3rd row ($\ce{Na, K, Ca}$), are arranged in same order as they are given in periodic table.

After studying them on periodic table for 15 minutes, it seemed to have no meaning. There are no periodic trends. $\ce{H, Li, Na, K, Rb}$ belongs to IA group, $\ce{Be, Ca, Sr}$ belongs to IIA group. And they are arranged in a random way, having no meaning.

**The picture is clearly a joke showing that when scientist have eye check-up, they have to read elements instead of alphabets.**

Comment: And that their left eye focuses on the left side of the periodic table.